# Implicit conversion from std::string to class doesn't work

Tags: c++

I get an error C2664 in Visual Studio 2010 saying that there is no conversion from `std::string` to my class `Filename`.

I don't really understand why this is happening, because I have constructors for accepting an `std::string` and this works for code like this:

```
std::string s = "t";
Filename f1 = s;
Filename f2(s);
```

However I have a function

```
FileType FileFactory::detectFileType(Filename &oFilename) const;
```

and in my code when I try to do

```
Filename fn = "d:\\tmp\\test.txt";

// getBaseDir() returns an std::string
FactoryFileType type = detectFileType(fn.getBaseDir());
```

it gets this error:

```
 error C2664: 'FileFactory::detectFileType': conversion of parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'Filename &' is not possible
```

My Filename class looks like this:

```
class Filename
{
public:
    Filename(std::string const &oFilename, std::string const &oBasePath = "");
    Filename(char const *oFilename = NULL, char const *oBasePath = NULL);
    Filename(const Filename &oSource);
    virtual ~Filename(void);

    void setBasePath(std::string const &oBasePath);
    void setBasePath(const char *oBasePath);

    const std::string &getBasePath(void) const;

    std::string getBaseDir(void) const;
    std::string getFileDir(void) const;

};
```

Comment: You cannot bind a temporary to a non-const ref. Change your parameter to const.

Comment: Unfortunately this function may need to modify the passed in object, why I did it not make const. At least I understand now the problem and have to see how to fix it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, that you function receives reference to `FileName`, but you are trying to pass `rvalue` to it. It's incorrect, temporary value cannot be binded to `lvalue-reference`, change parameter to `const reference`, or create `FileName` object and pass it.

Comment: I got also an error from intellisense `initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue` which makes it much clearer. I see now the problem. Thanks!